# Frequency Modulation Voltage Formula Derivation

Tags: voltage, frequency, modulation

I am taking Keysight "Signal Generation and Digital Modulation" Webinar. In class, frequency modulation is described in the slide below. The modulated (carrier signal added with transmitted signal) signal frequency is proportional to transmitted signal frequency. Can anyone give derivation of the voltage formula below including the definition of the variables? I can't find good description/derivation online. Also, when I try to graph it (y = cos(x + sin(x)), I am not getting the modulated signal like shown below. How could I see this relationship graphically?

[image: Frequency Modulation]

[image: my graphs]

Comment: What do you get if you graphed y = cos(x)?

Comment: I am getting normal cosine wave graph at y = cos(x) (shown as second graph above). Also, I tried to graph y = cos(x + sin(x)), but I am not getting the graph above.

Comment: Have you realized that \$f_c\$ (carrier frequency) should be much larger than \$F_m\$ (modulation frequency)? So instead of y = cos (x + sin(x)), try y = cos (10 x + sin(x)). Typical example: an AM radio station broadcasting a tone of 1 kHz (a beep) using a transmitter with a carrier of 1000 kHz, : \$f_c\$ = 1E6, \$F_m\$ = 1E3. So \$f_c\$ = 1000 x \$F_M\$ !

Answer (score 1):

> Also, when I try to graph it (y = cos(x + sin(x)), I am not getting the modulated signal like shown below.

You're not being asked to graph y = cos(x + sin(x)), you're being asked to graph y = cos(x + sin(y)), where y is related to the modulation.

y(t) is the carrier voltage.

For the unmodulated carrier at a frequency of fc, the phase of the carrier is f<sub>c</sub>t, so \$y(t) = Acos(2\pi f_ct)\$

Phase modulation disturbs the phase of the carrier. The phase of the modulation p<sub>m</sub> at a modulation frequency of f<sub>m</sub> is p<sub>m</sub> = f<sub>m</sub>t, where f<sub>m</sub> is a simple sinuosoid. Note that if the modulation signal is f<sub>m</sub>(t), the modulation phase will be \$p_m=\int_0^tf_mdt\$. This is the phase of the modulation signal. The phase amplitude (the amount by which the modulation disturbs the phase of the carrier) of the modulation is \$\beta sin(p_m)\$, where β is the modulation index, the amplitude of the phase modulation, in radians.

Putting those two together, you get \$y(t)=Acos(2\pi f_ct+\beta sin(f_mt) )  \$